# Append svg from file in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I have a SVG container and I want to append an image from a SVG file.

What i know is the method with image-tag but i won't be able to edit the svg content of this image anymore.
I looked for a more javascript way and used the .xml function of D3:

```
d3.xml("/svg/test.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml) {
    document.getElementById("mysvg").appendChild(xml.documentElement);
});
```

This works as intended (appends whole svg file to existing svg container).
Now i have tag in my tag is this a problem?
Is there any other solution for appending the whole svg file as its real source and not only a link?
I really need to edit the svg afterwards (set colors and stuf).

Please help me:)

Comment: what html is this returning?

Comment: something like <svg> <svg> ###image content here ###</svg></svg>

Comment: so then would this work? document.getElementById("mysvg") =  (xml.documentElement)

Comment: no, i want to add this xml tags like 12 times and then edit every single one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may or not be a problem to embed the SVG within the `mysvg` element; depends on what that element is. But if you want to replace it, something like the following should work:

```
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
mysvg.parentNode.replaceChild(xml.documentElement, mysvg);
```

You might have to convert the `documentElement` to a DOMnode.

Comment: I finally took the first child of the svg document and appended it to the svg. This worked, thanks